# Prisma: filter by most recent related model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I am currently working with the following Prisma models in a PostgreSQL db:

```
model Product {
  productId String @id
  name String
  color String
  events ProductEvent[]
  // ...
}

model ProductEvent {
  productEventId String @id
  productId String
  datetime DateTime
  status String
  product Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [productId])
}
```

I would like to be able to query my products by status (that is, by filtering by the `status` property of the ProductEvent with the most recent `datetime`).

My query looks like this at the moment:

```js
await this.client.product.findMany({
  include: {
    events: {
      orderBy: { datetime: "desc" },
      take: 1,
    },
  },
  where: {
    events: {
      some: {
        status: "WHATEVER_STATUS"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Of course, the where clause ignores what happens in the include statement and looks at all the events related to the product (not what I want).

Is there a way to force prisma to filter using only by the selected fields rather than by all the fields in the database? Would there be be another way for me to select a product by status?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by running two separate queries:

1. Query `ProductEvent` to find the latest events that have the desired status.
2. Query `Product` based on the productId of the events found in the first query.

```js
// Find the most recent event of each product that has the desired status
const latestEvents = await this.client.productEvent.findMany({
  where: {
    status: 'WHATEVER_STATUS',
  },
  orderBy: {
    datetime: 'desc',
  },
  take: 1,
});

// Extract the product IDs from the events
const productIds = latestEvents.map(event => event.productId);

const products = await this.client.product.findMany({
  where: {
    productId: {
      in: productIds,
    },
  },
  include: {
    events: true,
  },
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the first query will always return only one ProductEvent. What I want is to get all (or a certain number of) products for which their most recent event is of status WHATEVER_STATUS